# How to find out which VM i have in my Python installation?

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I installed Python in my PC. how to find out which VM came with it.

is it cpython or ipython or jpython?

Comment: iPython is not a VM, but an enhanced interactive interpreter.

Comment: true. my question should have been 'how to find out which implementation runs my python programs.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import platform
platform.python_implementation()
```

From the documentation:

```
platform.python_implementation()

     Returns a string identifying the Python implementation.
     Possible return values are: ‘CPython’, ‘IronPython’, ‘Jython’, ‘PyPy’.
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html

Comment: Please learn to indent - look at the preview under your editing

Answer (score 0):

Run this in command prompt

python -c "from platform import python_implementation; print python_implementation()"